# website panel error after windows update : Type is not allowed in the XML document

Tags: xml, windows, web-config, websitepanel

So after the last update of some windows machines running website panel I got this error under:
serveradmin->username ->My Server->Web Sites.

This is the error:

> Page URL:  url....
> Logged User:  username Work on Behalf:    admin Hosting Space:    4 Stack
> Trace:    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML
> document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Type
> 'WebsitePanel.Providers.ResultObjects.HeliconApeStatus,
> WebsitePanel.Providers.Base, Version=2.0.0.274, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=da8782a6fc4d0081' is not allowed here. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132227 for more information.
> at System.Data.TypeLimiter.EnsureTypeIsAllowed(Type type, TypeLimiter
> capturedLimiter) at System.Data.DataColumn.UpdateColumnType(Type type,
> StorageType typeCode) at System.Data.DataColumn.set_DataType(Type
> value) at System.Data.XSDSchema.SetProperties(Object instance,
> XmlAttribute[] attrs) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem,
> DataTable table, Boolean isBase) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable
> table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct,
> DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node,
> XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node) at
> System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleDataSet(XmlSchemaElement node, Boolean
> isNewDataSet) at System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet
> schemaSet, DataSet ds) at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader
> reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving) at
> System.Data.DataSet.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader
> reader) at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadSerializable(IXmlSerializable
> serializable, Boolean wrappedAny) at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderesPackages.Read54_Item()
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
> message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
> asyncCall) at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
> methodName, Object[] parameters) at
> WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.esPackages.GetRawPackageItemsPaged(Int32
> packageId, String groupName, String typeName, Int32 serverId, Boolean
> recursive, String filterColumn, String filterValue, String sortColumn,
> Int32 startRow, Int32 maximumRows) at
> WebsitePanel.Portal.ServiceItemsHelper.GetServiceItemsPaged(Int32
> packageId, String groupName, String typeName, Int32 serverId, Boolean
> recursive, String filterColumn, String filterValue, Int32 maximumRows,
> Int32 startRowIndex, String sortColumn)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod
> method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance)

There in more info on the error at this [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132227).

This is how I fixed this problem.

1. Go to website panel portal root location. In my case it's:
   `C:\WebsitePanel\Portal`
2. Make a backup of web.config file.
3. In web.config file find `<configSections>` and add this inside:
   `<sectionGroup name="system.data.dataset.serialization" type="System.Data.SerializationSettingsSectionGroup, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><section name="allowedTypes" type="System.Data.AllowedTypesSectionHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/></sectionGroup>`

If you don't have configSections section just add the code inside:

`<configSections>...</configSections>`

4. After the close of configSections section add this code:

`<system.data.dataset.serialization><allowedTypes><add type="WebsitePanel.Providers.ResultObjects.HeliconApeStatus, WebsitePanel.Providers.Base, Version=2.0.0.274, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=da8782a6fc4d0081" /></allowedTypes></system.data.dataset.serialization>`

If you have a different version of website panel just edit type to match your error message.
The type should contain the Type in your error message.

5. Save web.config, Restart the website panel portal and test.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have "configSections" you should create it, but it should
be the first child element of "configuration".

After creating the above elements, you will have to put only the below
code inside "configSections"

```
<configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.data.dataset.serialization" 
type="System.Data.SerializationSettingsSectionGroup, System.Data, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="allowedTypes" 
type="System.Data.AllowedTypesSectionHandler, System.Data, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

After the element "configSections", you will have to add the below
code.

```
<system.data.dataset.serialization>
    <allowedTypes>
      <!-- <add type="assembly qualified type name" /> -->
      <add type="Fabrikam.CustomType, Fabrikam, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutra`l`, PublicKeyToken=2b3831f2f2b744f7" />
     <!-- additional <add /> elements as needed -->
    </allowedTypes>
</system.data.dataset.serialization>
```